# font-style:oblique not working in chrome, Opera and Safari

Tags: css

Font-style oblique not working in Chrome, Opera and Safari. But working in Firefox and IE8. What is the solution plz?

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'TFC';
src: url('font/too_freakin_cute_demo-webfont.eot');
src: url('font/too_freakin_cute_demo-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('font/too_freakin_cute_demo-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('font/too_freakin_cute_demo-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('font/too_freakin_cute_demo-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('font/too_freakin_cute_demo-webfont.svg#too_freakin_cute_demoregular') format('svg');}

body p{
font-family: 'TFC';
font-style:oblique;}
```

Comment: Is this an issue with this particular font only? If so, can you provide a working demo? I can't seem to find this font on the web for download, so I can't test.

Comment: Well, I used one from Google Fonts, the same problem is also with that. This is the one I used
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>